# Java parse values until the end of line

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

Easy question - probably - but I don't find a solution without a workaround.

I want to parse sth. like

```
1) item1;; item3
2) item1;item2;
3) ; item2;
4) ;;
...
```

I have a matching function that matches and returns all items at a given index as stringlist:

```
public static List<String> getAllMatchings(String input, String reg, int groupIndex) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(reg);     
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);   

    List<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (matcher.find()) {
        if (groupIndex <= matcher.groupCount()) {
            ls.add(matcher.group(groupIndex));
        }
    }

    return ls;
}
```

Now, having such a row, I want to have a stringlist like { "item1", "item2", "item3" }. But I get - using my solution - { "item1", "item2", "item3", "" }:

```
List<String> strList = getAllMatchings(line, "([^;]*)(;|\\z)",1);
```

And thus, I have to make an ugly workaround:

```
strList.remove(strList.size()-1);
```

Not nice. But I don't find a solution for that problem. Can someone help me?

**Addition**: By the way. There is case where this workaround doesn't work. Case 4) gives me only 2 empty elements.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just split on semicolon?

UPDATE: count the semicolons to ensure the right number of elements

```
int count = StringUtils.countMatches("item1;item2;;;;", ";");
String[] values = input.split(";",count);
```

(requires [Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/))

Comment: Because I want to be flexible to set a more specific pattern for the matching elements

Comment: String.split accepts a regex, so it might suit your usage. I'd recommend this unless you need to add logic into the extraction.

Comment: what about the following? String row = "item1;;;" String[]b = a.split(";"). A result with side-effects. :/ I need a four-element-array here.

Comment: So you expect items 2, 3, & 4 to be empty strings? Your other examples have spaces after the semicolon - this would equate to an input string of "item 1; ; ; "

Comment: Spaces are optional. Thats the problem with the solution of Grimmy. It would work otherwise :/

Comment: I see; using row.split() gives an array with just one element. if you always have four data items, you can use row.split(";",4);

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect this, and added code to count; this ensures the right number of elements in the array.

Comment: This is a workaround. I implemented it and it fits my requirements. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add items only if they are not empty:

```
String item = matcher.group(groupIndex).trim();
if (!item.isEmpty()) {
    ls.add(item);
}
```

Comment: Sry,there is a problem on sth. like "item1;;item3", cause items can be empty. I changed my question a little bit cause I didn't mention that

Answer (score 0):

if the quote are not part of your string you can use the `split` method on String:

```
String input = "item1; item2; item3";
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(input.split("; ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter either on the empty string or the matcher.start/end being equal.